# System.out.print did not work as intended

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I am currently doing a school project in java (I use NetBeans) and I come across this problem. I have done some online research but no luck so far. Here is a snippet of my code:
the problem is that whenever I click run file, the console only displays the message in the help() method but not this message "Command [c/r/u/d/x]". the message is only shown after input any of the possible options. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Console output]

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException { 
    new TestDB().menu(); 
    } 

    private DBConnector connector; 
    private Connection conn; 
    private DBManager manager; 
    public TestDB() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException { 
    connector = new DBConnector(); conn = connector.openConnection(); 
    manager = new DBManager(conn);    
    }

private void testCreate() throws SQLException {
        System.out.println("Adding customer to the database: ");
        manager.addCustomer(read("Email"),read("Password"),read("First 
        Name"),read("Last Name"),read("Phone 
        Num"),read("Address"),read("DOB"));
            System.out.println("Customer added successfully ");
        }
    private String read(String prompt) {
        System.out.print(prompt + ": ");
        System.out.flush();
        return in.nextLine();
    }

    private String read(int prompt) {
        System.out.print(prompt + ": ");
        System.out.flush();
        return in.nextLine();
    }

    private void menu() throws SQLException {
        char c;
        help();
        
        
        while ((c = read("Command [c/r/u/d/f/x]").charAt(0)) != 'x') {
            switch (c) {
                case 'c':
                    testCreate();
                    break;
                case 'r':
                    testFind();
                    break;
                case 'u':
                    testUpdate();
                    break;
                case 'd':
                    testDelete();
                    break;
                default:
                    help();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void help() {
        System.out.println("Database Operations: \n"
                + "c = Create User \n"
                + "r = Find User \n"
                + "u = Update User \n"
                + "d = Delete User \n");
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your `main()` method?

Comment: Here it is:

public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        new TestDB().menu();
    }

    private DBConnector connector;
    private Connection conn;
    private DBManager manager;

    public TestDB() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        connector = new DBConnector();
        conn = connector.openConnection();
        manager = new DBManager(conn);
    }

Comment: Try this and let me know if it worked: `c = read("Command [c/r/u/d/x]"); c.charAt(0);`

Comment: Hi, I try yours but c's type is char so Netbean did not compile it.

Comment: Edit your question to include your main() method, don't paste it on the comments.

Comment: @user16320675, Hi, I try yours but the result is still same. Thanks for your time anyway.

Comment: @m0skit0, updated! Thanks.

Comment: hi, thanks I forgot to update the newest version of that part so it will cause a loop but even after I do that the old issue is still exist. I suspect it has somethings to do with the buffer of System.out.print as when I change that to System.out.println, the issue resolve even though the cursor moves to the below line which is not exactly what I want. I also try System.out.flush but the result is still the same

Comment: That code won't compile, please post a compilable example that reproduces the problem and properly formatted.

Comment: Hi, the code definitely will not compile since it just a snippet of my project but please don't worry yourself about this issue. I managed to fix it and I have posted the solution below. Just waiting for the cooldown to end  to accept the answer. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved, I just replace print() to println() in my read() method. The problem seems to belong to some different between maven and ant project. I try the same code in ant and it execute perfectly.

New update:
this site help me: https://github.com/mojohaus/exec-maven-plugin/issues/159.
Basically, you just need to change the goal from exec:exec to exec:java

[See detail here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmFEM.png)

Comment: yep thank you, have updated the newest version of posted code. I just change the while loop to this:
while ((c = read("Command [c/r/u/d/f/x]").charAt(0)) != 'x')

Answer (score 0):

I think you must enter the all the user input "Email","Password","First Name","Last
Name","Phone Num","Address","DOB" after entering each value press enter. Once u enter all the values remaining code will be exectued.

Comment: yeah it works and the sql command also work perfectly too, it just that I want the console to prompt the user about what information they should type. Like this:
email: abc@gmail.com
password:123